# How to add android.view.View dependency to an external module?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an external module in my Android project named *gs_graphics_kit*

[image]

In this module, I have some class where I want to use the **View** object (from the *android.view* package). However, this package is not recognizable under this module.
I believe this is a dependency problem, but I can't figure out how to add this dependency.

Any help please ?

**EDIT**
The build.gradle file for this module is the following :

```
apply plugin: "java"
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ["src/"]
eclipse.project {
}
dependencies {
}
```

Comment: show the gradle file of this module

Comment: I've edited the post to show the build.gradle file of this module

Comment: i think you should appcompat dependency in you external module gradle

Comment: I ave added implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' to the build.gradle dependencies section but it still does not work